# RecyclerView content goes behind and not over TextView above

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Consider this video from material design on drag & dropping items:

[Material design reordering list](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-components%2Fassets%2F1dtprsH4jZ2nOnjBCJeJXd7n4U-jmWyas%2F03-list-reorder.mp4)

In the video you see a RecyclerView and above it a TextView with the text "Playlist". When the row is dragged up you see it going over the Playlist.

In my code the row goes behind the Textview. I've put RecyclerView's layout_height to match_parent. And I used a FrameLayout and placed the TextView below the RecyclerView. Why isn't it going over it?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_margin"
        android:text="@string/activity_bible_order_explanation"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: what is the parent layout?

Comment: sorry, indenting! Framelayout.

Comment: just switch the position 
<FrameLayout  covert to <LinearLayout> with vertical orientation

Comment: Recycler view should be 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
weightSum= "1"

Comment: @AkarshM doesn't work, same issue.

Comment: LinearLayout with orientation vertical should work. and make recyclerview to wrap_content

Comment: @Nik this doesn't work.

Comment: use constraint layout.and set recycle-view height match parent. and in recycle view set first item as empty and view as invisible.

Comment: you can follow this link https://www.journaldev.com/23208/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop  may it will help you!!!

Comment: @JimClermonts , According to android framework , FrameLayout is the layout which will  drawn it's Child views in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout

Answer (score 4):

Use Constraint layout as a parent layout and add textview at the top by giving top constraints to the textview. then add
recyclerview's top constraint to the the bottom of textview and recyclerview bottom constraint to the bottom of parent then set height 0 it will work

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/general_margin"
            android:text="@string/activity_bible_order_explanation"
            />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintTop_toTopOf not found. Is there a special library needed?

Comment: did you add constraint layout?

Comment: please post your latest layout file

Comment: don't set your recycler view height as matchparent

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried elevation? the problem might be that in the z axis the TextView is higher than the RecyclerView. try adding `android:elevation="10dp"` or higher... like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_margin"
        android:text="@string/activity_bible_order_explanation"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp" (if it doesn't work try maybe higher elevation, 20dp etc.)
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it works for you (: let me know!

Answer (score 0):

What is the parent layout of this?

Because you set `match_parent` in recyclerview  and list have many content that's why this issue facing.

Please give fix height or use relative layout and apply position above of text view in  recyclerview

Comment: but it has to be match_parent otherwise it will never go beyond it's own bounds.

Comment: @JimClermonts Please use ScrollView or NestedScrollView as a parent of this both and set recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false). I hope you looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your layout code:

1. You're using a `FrameLayout`
2. Inside `FrameLayout`, you're also using top margin on your `RecyclerView`
   `android:layout_marginTop="96dp"` `<--` This causing the issue.

**Solution:**

- You should `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`. And, also set `LinearLayout`'s orientation as vertical. 
  `android:orientation="vertical"`
- Also remove this line from your `RecyclerView`:-
  `android:layout_marginTop="96dp"`

**Solution Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I tried your solution and it isn't working.

Comment: You can also try `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not that the dragged view is going behind the *TextView* but, rather, the dragged view is not being drawn outside the bounds of the *RecyclerView*. The effect is the same.

To allow the *RecyclerView* to draw outside of itself, set the following for the *parent* of the *RecyclerView*:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

For the *RecyclerView* set

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `RecyclerView` is above the text view in your `FrameLayout`. Currently, it appears that the underlying `TextView` is above the `RecyclerView` as you have given the background for the `RecyclerView` as:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

To make this work as normal, either remove this line or change the background of `RecyclerView`  to any value other than transparent.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 more issue. You need to place the recycler view first. Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World"/>

</LinearLayout>
```